# Android Things random rebooting and restarting on Raspberry Pi 3. Power cycling

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

I physically moved my android things project to a new physical environment. When plugged in to that environment, it now constantly reboots and power cycles. In my development environment the power remains stable and Android Things actual launches.

In the new environment, occasionally it may launch and actually display, but for the most part in that environment, it just restarts and reboots repeatedly.

I've tried 2 different usb cables, standard ones that charge various android phones.

What is the best practice for keeping Android Things power stable in any physical environment?

Comment: If not related to cables, it may be related to your power source.

Comment: Use another power supply. Not USB cables and not _"standard ones that charge various android phones"_.

Comment: 1. You need power supply with stable [at least 2.1A](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/) on 5V (better 2.5A). 2. Check all wire connections for shorts.

Comment: This question better to ask at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I am using a good(multiple) USB cables; a PSU that can more than handle 2.5A; red light constant; multiple Pi Boards; disk image written multiple times and verified; Rasperian works perfectly under high load, for long periods of time. Shortly after booting into the initial setup, the board restarts.

Comment: Same here, found out that it is in a way related to Wifi, since when I disable Wifi, there are no more reboots. Tried to create a custom image in the Things Console, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

> When plugged in to a new environment, it now constantly reboots and power cycles.

Most likely the problem is the [power supply](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/44519/70348) which isn't powerful enough for *Pi 3*.

It is [officially recommended to use a power supply of 2.1 - 2.5A](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#power-supply)

> I've tried 2 different usb cables, standard ones that charge various android phones.

In most cases [USB cables used for regular *Android* phones aren't enough for *Pi 3*](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=138636).